# How can I draw a circle in TGA, if we know a radius and coordinates x,y?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int i,j,k,r=5,x=20,y=20,d,a,l;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            a=((i-x)(i-x))+((j-y)(j-y));
            d=sqrt(a);
            if(r>=d)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            else
                printf(" ");
        }   
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format your code and what is TGA? Your question is not clear.

Comment: If we reopen this question, it will just be closed again as a "typo", I guess? Note: I've undone a previous edit that 'corrected' the code, as this is bad form (didn't notice it when I first 'improved' that edit from the review queue).

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is the line `a=((i-x)(i-x))+((j-y)(j-y));`  you didn't use the multiplication operator, `*`. It should be like this `a = ((i-x)*(i-x)) + ((j-y)*(j-y));`.